# Set breakpoint in package referenced via nuget?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

I have an ASP.Net website, built with VS 2013, that uses Nuget to reference a package.  I rebuilt this other package (also with VS 2013) and copied its resulting dll to the website's `packages\<this other package>\lib` folder, to get the recently built version of the package into the mix without doing a Nuget publish.

Is it then possible to set a breakpoint somehow and step into /see this other package's code?

Comment: Are you able to set breakpoint in target library?

Comment: I can set one there, but can I hit it / pause on it somehow?

Comment: Is the software you're trying to debug open source?

Comment: if you can set breakpoint, consequently you can debug application. Press F9 to set breakpoint and press F5 to run the program till the breakpoint.

Comment: @StepUp I see now.  Previously I set a breakpoint in the target, and attached the debugger to the IIS / w3wp.exe instance, but the breakpoint was never hit.  But when I copied the dll _and_ the pdb file to the website's package folder, the breakpoint was hit after attaching the debugger.

Comment: @mason: it's not open source, but I do have the source internally.